# In HTML, how can I make a button that reverse sorts a massive

Tags: php, html

In HTML, how can I make a button that reverse sorts a massive.. $m = explode($s) 
form_method="POST"

Comment: Firstly, Welcome to SO, other members of the community will be glad to help in anyway they can, but for us to do so we need you to me more specific in your question, Please try and explain in detail what you need, any examples of your previous attempts, desired outcome etc, please dont treat SO As a forum, its a community wiki, you have av ery short amount of time before the question gets closed for lack of description / not a full quistion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean client-side, not just HTML. If so, use `Array.sort()`.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

"Massive" is a completely relative term, but I have tested `Array.Sort` with complex object sorts for arrays containing a couple thousand items with no issues.

Simplified, it looks like this.

```
<input type="button" onclick="PerformSort()" />

<script>

function PerformSort()
{

var arr = [];

// populate 'arr' with items to sort

arr.sort();

// output sorted results to DOM

}

</script>
```